# Automatic field reversal on API actions

Tags: soql, rest-api, api, soap-api

I've got a Python app that's using the [simple-salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce) Salesforce API client. One operation that it performs is automatic re-assignment of contact owners based on the owner of the respective account, i.e. if Joe Schmoe is a contact owned by John Doe on the Big Company account, but the owner of the Big Company account is Jane Smith, Joe Schmoe's contact owner would be switched to Jane Smith automatically.

When I look at the history in Salesforce, it shows that the contact owner was changed properly, but then some time later, that change is reversed, i.e. Joe Schmoe's contact owner gets switched back to John Doe.

I've looked into our workflow rules, and nothing is present that would cause this to roll back. Is there protocol built into the platform that would cause this?

Note: this **does not happen every time.** We've seen it happen mostly on enterprise-level accounts with a higher volume of contacts.

Comment: Are you triggering assignment rules? Do you have triggers? There's a variety of reasons why this might happen, and you'll need to learn to read the debug logs to figure out exactly what.

Comment: [but then some time later, that change is reversed] -- the history should capture that too, so you may like to take a look which User changed it and try to trace it back to the root cause.

Comment: @JayantDas it all happens under the same user, but often with half an hour to an hour between changes.

Comment: Can it happen when u were changing owner, the record was opened in edit mode by an user or via some batch process running in parallel, It can happen your update was superseded by the update of user or batch

Comment: Does the Account Owner happen to change as well within this time?

Comment: @JayantDas it does not.

Comment: Then there must be some other entry point (workflow, trigger, etc.) into the record which makes the updates, which you would need to look for.